# CAML query to filter Datetime

Tags: development, caml-query

I have to filter data with respect to a field named `CreatedDate` having type **datetime**.

In input I'm just giving date (not time), I want to fetch all records with respect to specific **date (ignoring time)**, I want to use CAML query to do this.
How should I ignore time and search by just giving date as input.

Currently, I'm using this CAML query to search:

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Created'/>
  <Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'>" + createdDate + "</Value></Eq></Where>
```

Comment: OMG, it worked perfectly :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this : --->** createdDate.ToString("s")

Comment: No problem. Come again:))

Comment: This works for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Please note that date you are passing in **CAML query** need to be in **ISO8601DateTime** format.

```
string createdDate = startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
```

then pass this in CAML query.

Reference: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/414414/SharePoint-Working-with-Dates-in-CAML

Comment: actually i dont want to give time as i said in my question "i have to ignore time in my input".

Comment: However; Goshy's answer worked for me : createdDate.ToString("s")

Comment: Yeah. You can use above code even without passing time. You need to just pass formatted string in CAML query. Both answers are right. :)